# Обработка ошибки в функции в MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Как Обработать ошибки в пользовательской функции в MS SQL Server? `try...catch` в ней не разрешены, а что надо делать?

Comment: Вернуть результат из функции который бы сигнализировал бы об ошибке.

Comment: Какого вида ошибки вы собираетесь обрабатывать внутри функции? Что должно произойти в теле функции, чтобы сгенерировалась ошибка выполнения? Приведите конкретный пример.

Answer (score 1):

Сформировать ошибку Raise-ом не получится.
Но! Можно сделать специально ошибку. Например, сделать SELECT CAST('<Маркер_сообщения>Сообщение' AS Int), что приведет к ошибке CAST-а. А уже выше уровнем, где ловится ошибка обработать следующее сообщение:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '<Маркер_сообщения>Сообщение' to data type int.

Естественно, придется исходное сообщение вырезать и сделать снова RaisError уже с исходным сообщением.

Если у вас стандартная процедура обработки ошибок и используется во всех(!) CATCH-ах, то такой подход вполне может сработать.